# Import multiple .dat files into separate data frames

Tags: r, import, dataframe

I'm quite new to R. 
I have a folder that has about 400 datasets in .dat format. I would like to import them from the folder into saparated dataframes saving their original names. Inside files look as following:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7
3.34494983360861 -10.1551377245439 2.04729104928113 5.04839249647869 -4.81433102683924 2.70989181766111 -1.30457769064068
5.52064961416553 -12.3016190492607 0.101398882838427 -0.605507111814781 -2.96478714163403 7.62147991519767 -3.00260061456239
```

Thank you.

Comment: The best method in R is to read them into a list. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218498/reading-multiple-files-into-multiple-data-frames-in-r) for some tips and this one for [working with lists of data.frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207).

Answer (score 0):

It should not be too hard, see [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/merge-all-files-in-a-directory-using-r-into-a-single-dataframe/) to know the steps for listing all the files in the input directory.

Then, just create data frames as you require. Additionally, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664075/import-dat-file-into-r) for reading dat files.